# Asp.Net MVC Post Controller Not being hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got an Asp.Net mvc web app that has a controller action to handle a post with an int as a parameter.  I've set a breakpoint in the action and it is never getting hit.  Here is the controller action setup:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AddTestNumber(int number)
    {
```

And here is the jquery that calls the action:

```
$.post("/testController/AddTestNumber/852852");
```

I've tested it with no parameters and it hit the breakpoint.  I havent changed any routing, so thats set to default.

This seems like it should be very simple fix that I'm overlooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

Your URL doesn't need to contain 'Controller'. 
i.e.

```
$.post("/Test/AddTestNumber/852852");
```

If you want the parameter to be in the URL, rather than in the query-string, and you are using default routing, then I believe the parameter needs to named 'id'.
i.e.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddTestNumber(int id)
{
```

Otherwise, you need to pass it via the query-string.
i.e.

```
$.post("/Test/AddTestNumber?number=852852");
```

or add custom routing rules.

I hope one of those helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

yes the fix is easy. if you did not change routing, in stead of int number, use int id.
now the router looks for a 'number', but in your url you dont have a number, just an id.